# How can I determine the type of magnet used in a DC motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, home-experiment

I repair electrical motors in a workshop and sometimes I must repair permanent magnet DC motors and other motors that use permanent magnets.  I need to specify type of permanent magnet (Ferrite or Alnico or rare earth, etc.) by a simple method. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: get hold of one of these ? http://www.niton.com/en/niton-analyzers-products

Comment: Measure the density and look at the physical appearance of the surface. I think those two factors would probably narrow it down quite a bit. If that's not enough, maybe measure the dipole moment based on deflection of a compass, and determine the ratio of dipole moment to mass, $D/m$.